# Check a user-entered string is of format "%d/%d/%d/%d/%d" in C

Tags: c, linux, format, scanf

I tried checking the format of the string by using `sscanf()`. It does not print the error even if it does not matche the format. I don't know what is wrong in it.

```
char        *now = 1; // assume this is the user-entered string
int         year,month,hour,min,sec;

//CHECKING IF THE ARGUMENT IS CORRECT OR NOT
if (sscanf(now,"%d/%d/%d/%d/%d\n",&year,&month,&hour,&min,&sec) == 0)   
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\x1b[1;31mMust specify correct format\nExiting........\x1b[0m\n");
        _exit(1);   
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you expect `char *now = 1` to do.  Are you intending to initialize the pointer to 1?

Comment: ...or, piggy backing on last comment, check for `EOF` per _[this sscanf documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm)_.

Comment: @ryyker Yes. Assume like char *now = 2000/300/2. It should give an error as it is not of the format %d/%d/%d/%d/%d

Comment: `char *now = 2000/300/2` is not a legal initialization.  Niether is: `char        *now = 1;`.  It would be okay to do `char *now = "2000/300/2"`

Comment: `sscanf()` returns the number of fields successfully assigned (or EOF on error)...

Comment: @xing yes it works!

Comment: I am not sure what worked, but you should consider all of the comments here, and check your compile-time error messages.  The code you show does not compile, so it would not have run.

Comment: @ryyker actually i wanted to take 'now' as a command line argument, which works in my program. I had copied the command line argument to char * now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sscanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) returns the number of fields successfully scanned and assigned (or `EOF` in case of an error). You are checking if none of the `%d`s were successful, i.e, no number was parsed from the string. This means that even if one integer could be parsed, then the `if` will not execute. So change

```
if (sscanf(now,"%d/%d/%d/%d/%d\n",&year,&month,&hour,&min,&sec) == 0)
```

to

```
if (sscanf(now, "%d/%d/%d/%d/%d", &year, &month, &hour, &min, &sec) != 5)
```

which executes the `if` even when one number could not be parsed. I've removed the `\n` because it doesn't really have any effect here.